# Android - Artifacts using Animation

Tags: android, animation

I am having a problem with visual artifacts on the screen when applying the 3D transformation found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.html). I have changed this so it rotates around the x axis instead of the y. When i do a full 180 rotation (top going away from you at first) im getting single pixel line artifacts at the bottom area (bottom 10-20%) of every other view that this is applied to. I am using a selector as the background of a LinearLayout and then applying this Animation to it. Can anyone think of a quick solution to this issue?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just had the same issue, only comment I would add is that on 1.6 - pre 3.0 devices I get the artefacts, but on 3.0+ devices, enabling hardware acceleration solves the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out you just have to invalidate the parent view on each animation step. If you have a custom Animation object you can just do this inside Animation.applyTransformation(...)

Comment: glad to be of service - i knew answering my own questions would come in useful someday :)

Comment: Just ran into this as well, cleared up the problems I was having.  This bug only seemed to affect 2.3 and lower devices (including the Kindle Fire) and seemed fine on my various 4.0+ devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem with a 2D animation where a View is moved off screen (outside parent view). My solution was quite simple. In my custom View I simply invalidate the parent view to have it redrawn at every frame.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    ((View) this.getParent()).invalidate();
    canvas.drawBitmap(icon, bm_x, bm_y, mPaint);
}
```